Running 'npx expo start --tunnel' throws TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string
I am playing around with React Native and Expo, following one of Expo's getting started tutorials.
I ran:
npx create-expo-app StickerSmash --template blank
npx expo start

That works fine for web and with my Android studio emulator.
When I scan the QR code in the terminal with my iPhone (which is on the same home wifi network as my laptop) expo does not connect - it says 'This is taking much longer than it should. You might want to check your internet connectivity.'
I unsuccessfully tried:
StickerSmash> npx expo start --tunnel
Starting project at C:\Users\...\StickerSmash
Starting Metro Bundler
CommandError: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received null
Check the Ngrok status page for outages: https://status.ngrok.com/

I also tried:

checking that Ngrok is Working
-restarting my pc
running expo start -c

Would be nice to see the app running on my iPhone, but I don't really know what to do next.
